# Is it possible for angular2 to import components from another angular2 project?

Tags: angular

Having the structure below:

```
/project1
   /app
      /components
      /services
index.html

/project2
   /app
      /components
      /services
index.html
```

Is it possible to import a component or service from project2 to project1 and vice versa?

Comment: yes you can you should have to place your both projects into some common folder.  i have't tried yet same may be it is possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could configure SystemJS to use both folders in your `index.html` file. This way you will be able to import project elements into another one.

```
<script>
  System.config({
    packages: {        
      'project1/app': {
        format: 'register',
        defaultExtension: 'js'
      },
      'project2/app': {
        format: 'register',
        defaultExtension: 'js'
      }
    }
  });
  System.import('project1/app/boot')
        .then(null, console.error.bind(console));
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

To **import the component (or) service** from another angular2 project you **follow the following steps**

1. **export** the needed **component and service from a project 1**.
2. install that project using npm (example : **npm install ../project1**)
3. **Add the path in System config file**
4. Now the **exported component and services are accesable in project 2**,So you can **import the project1 components and services** as per your need.